# Python2.7 argparse.parse_known_args parsing incorrectly

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

**background**
I have a script where I am using `parseargs` to partially parse the input.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-c", action="store_true")
nspc = parser.parse_known_args()
```

The reason for using parseargs is to allow the -c option to occur anywhere in the input. I only want to parse this option, and then later in the code I do additional parsing on my own. The reason for this is, the script accepts a large number of arguments from a **configuration file**, ie, myscript.py doesn't know the arguments until runtime.

**problem** The problem I am running into is, some of the arguments may start with the letter "c.", so if I say

```
$ myscript.py "some argument" -cdef
```

I get the error

myscript.py: error: argument -c: ignored explicit argument 'ef'

Since I said `parser.add_argument("-c", ...` I would expect that `-c` would be parsed but `-cdef` would not. Obviously, `-c` is an optional argument.

How can I tell the parser that `-c` is an option but `-cdef` is not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `--` for multi-character argument names.

It's fairly common in UNIX for `-cdef` to mean `-c -d -e -f`, whereas `--cdef` is a single option. `argparse` follows this convention.

(As an example: `ls -la` is the equivalent of `ls -l -a`, whereas `ls --color` is just a single option.)

Comment: Wooow, I feel dumb. Thanks for the quick response!